# Spring boot docker updates do not appear

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am running a web project and a database through docker compose, but my updates do not appear on the page.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  app:
    image: springio/gs-spring-boot-docker
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - mypostgres
  mypostgres:
    image: image
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ps
     - POSTGRES_USER=us
     - POSTGRES_DB=db
```

I changed Application.java just printing instead of "Hello World" something, I refreshed page **localhost:8080** but still no changes in my web page
I changed

Comment: What docker commands are you running?

Comment: @AK47 docker-compose up

Comment: @AK47  how to build a new image and run it?

Comment: According to this you need to build a new image and then run it: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: Are you using mvn or gradle?

Comment: @AK47 I am using gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory of your Dockerfile and run the following commands:

Build the new image:

```
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker .
```

and then run the new image:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker
```

Comment: thanks it works. Now I have another problem when I d **docker compse up** `Connection to localhost:5432 refused.` Do I need to build postgre docker before running compose?

Comment: You would need to check the stack trace of the Connection refused message -- you should also post a new question for this new image

Comment: According this this, yes you should be building a postgres image and running it before you try to connect via the webapp: https://medium.com/@isurunuwanthilaka/docker-zero-to-hero-with-springboot-postgres-e0b8c3a4dccb

Comment: when I run it is written in console **"listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432"** Is it important maybe I am connecting to different ports?

Comment: 5432 is the default for postgres

Comment: You have `image: image` -- should the 2nd image be the actual postgresql image? What did you name your postgresql image?